# How to leave out META-INF/maven/... in JAR files produced by maven?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Maven seems to put its `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` into the JAR at `META-INF/maven/example.com/example.com.foo/pom.properties`.

How can I get it to leave those files out?

Comment: By changing the configuration of the maven-jar-plugin.

Comment: I guessed so :-) but how? I haven't been able to find out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is to take a look into the documentation for [Maven archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html)

This shows the possibilies which are usable:

```xml
<archive>
  <addMavenDescriptor/>
  <compress/>
  <forced/>
  <index/>
  <manifest>
    <addClasspath/>
    <addDefaultImplementationEntries/>
    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
    <addExtensions/>
    <classpathLayoutType/>
    <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout/>
    <classpathPrefix/>
    <customClasspathLayout/>
    <mainClass/>
    <packageName/>
    <useUniqueVersions/>
  </manifest>
  <manifestEntries>
    <key>value</key>
  </manifestEntries>
  <manifestFile/>
  <manifestSections>
    <manifestSection>
      <name/>
      <manifestEntries>
        <key>value</key>
      </manifestEntries>
    <manifestSection/>
  </manifestSections>
  <pomPropertiesFile/>
</archive>
```

If you change the configuration to prevent using the default by this:

```xml
<project>
  <url>http://some.url.org/</url>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

By using the above the defaults will not being part of your artifacts anymore. So from here you can start to customize the configuration based on your wishes.